# MySQL Design For High Frequency Billing System

Tags: mysql, multithreading, billing

I have a feeling I'm gonna get butchered for asking this question, but here it goes...

I have 5 million daily subscriptions & expect/hope to have 50million in 12 months. I need to renew/bill these very, very quickly. I've tried every permutation of index & looping I could think of, but its the SELECT queries are still too slow. Perhaps my mistake is MySQL design, perhaps its my daemon that uses MySQL, perhaps its simply because I'm using MySQL - please let me know your thoughts and/or advice. Thanks!

** Subscription Table looks like this **

- subscription_id (PK)
- subscriber_id
- service_id
- add_date
- current_start_date
- current_end_date
- bill_date (used to ensure two threads dont grab to bill at same time)
- last_successful_bill_date
- has_outstanding_balance

** Money-people-owe-me table looks like this ***

- id
- subscription_id (UK)
- outstanding_balance
- next_bill_date
- number_bill_attempts
- (a fair amount of people dont always pay, I give them unpaid access for a bit while I continue trying to bill, eventually I cut off their service though)

** Billing Daemon looks like this **

- Run multi-threaded on multiple machines:
- For each service

  - stuffToBill[] = SELECT stuff ORDER BY next_bill_date **FOR UPDATE** LIMIT XXX;
  - UPDATE stuff SET next_bill_date = later WHERE id IN (stuffToBill[ids])
  - COMMIT
  - Put them on a queue for billing workers

Running EXPLAIN shows that I'm using decent indexing, but nitty gritty of the SQL combined with the fact that I am running the same daemon on multiple servers makes it lock up / generally overload the I/O queue on my DBM. DBM is quality hardware.

Thanks again for your advice!

Comment: You wrote "I need to renew/bill these very, very quickly." This is an insufficient performance specification for a system of the scale you're describing.  You need to figure out how fast your *really* need this system to be. You need to figure out which operations need to happen in real time (while your user waits) and which, if any, can happen in an overnight billing run.

Comment: As fast as possible, but diminishing returns if i can loop all in a couple hours. The user isn't waiting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using a select / update / commit regime to determine which accounts to bill, as follows:

```
     SELECT stuff 
   ORDER BY next_bill_date 
 FOR UPDATE 
     LIMIT XXX;

    UPDATE stuff 
       SET next_bill_date = later
     WHERE id IN (stuffToBill[ids]);

    COMMIT;
```

Your SELECT statement can be improved by adding a workable `WHERE` clause that only chooses bills that are coming due, or by some other criterion. It makes little sense to look at all the bills just to find the oldest. Something like

```
  WHERE next_bill_date <= TODAY() + INTERVAL 30 DAYS
```

might do the trick.  If you do things right, the complexity of the SELECT query will be reduced. If you index next_bill_date correctly, you'll get to use an index.

You also might try messing around with the size of the `LIMIT BY xxxx` value.  It's possible you're using too large a value here, and your updates are unpleasantly slow.

Finally, you're going to need to look into doing some serious MySQL and InnoDB tuning. The preset parameters controlling such things as RAM usage ordinarily aren't right for production systems like yours.

Comment: Thanks. I had to dumb down the query, but it does have a where clause & indices on bill dates. I copied the database various other machines and permutated different queries and index's - but benchmarking shows minimal performance improvement for scaling above ~5 million rows. Any thoughts on design patterns, mem-caching, or other clever ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Caching is not going to help, because you have to read and then write the rows. Caching helps with multiple reads.  Design patterns: it should be possible to avoid scanning and sorting all your rows with each query.

Comment: Thanks Ollie, any suggestions on Design Patterns? Partitioning, changing the code around, etc. Thanks again!